# Python, How to stop a script midway?

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-7, interrupt, pause

Let's say I have this script:

```
import time

def menu():
    n = raw_input("What do you want the script to do: ").lower()
    if n == "run":
        r = run()
    elif n == "exit":
        exit()
    else:
        print("Unknown command")
    print("Result: " + r)    

def run():
    t = 0
    while t < 60:
        print("This script is doing some stuff")
        time.sleep(1)
        t = t + 1
    return "Some kind of result"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Starting the most useless script ever")
    while True:
        menu()
```

How can I stop the script while printing *"This script is doing some stuff"* and return to *Menu()*? I dont want to totally exit the program, just to return to menu.

Comment: Do you mean you want to stop it interactively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something along this:

```
while True:
    try:
        # whatever logic
        pass 
    except(KeyboardInterrupt):
        print 'Ctrl-C was pressed... interupt while loop.'
        break
print 'program still running'
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the signal library, all you'll need to do is create a function to handle it.

```
import signal

def a(sig_num, stack_frame):
    print("WORKS")

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT,a)
```

The function `a` has to have two positional arguments

Comment: Use Ctrl+C to make trigger the signal interrupt, aka `signal.SIGINT`